# UITableView ReloadData confusion

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

The way this works is, the cell is swiped left.. Delete button pressed, it accesses the local database and deletes the row with the relevant data. However, this is not what is happening.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //add code here for when you hit delete

        NSDictionary *dict = [_sourceData valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", indexPath.row]];

        Connection *connection = [[Connection alloc] init];

        [connection removeRowFromTable:@"sources" withRowID:[dict valueForKey:@"id"]];

        [self loadData];

        NSLog(@"%@", _sourceData);

        [_sourceTable reloadData];

    }
} //Delete Data Cell
```

So it creates a dictionary with the row id. Then initialises the connection class, removes the row from the table ( which works ), loads the data where it fills `_sourceData` with the data from the table. Logs the _sourceData which logs correctly for the right one deleted. However, reloading the data for source table does not work. It deletes `a` row, but not the right one. then if I were to exit that viewcontroller and return to it, it will display the correct data.

Example, if I delete the first row, it will delete the second row from the view on the tableview then, when I return to the view controller.. It's now deleted the right one.

_sourceData logs the correct data, the tableView doesn't show it.

I'll provide all of the tableView methods to help.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return YES if you want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //add code here for when you hit delete

        NSDictionary *dict = [_sourceData valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", indexPath.row]];

        Connection *connection = [[Connection alloc] init];

        [connection removeRowFromTable:@"sources" withRowID:[dict valueForKey:@"id"]];

        [self loadData];

        NSLog(@"%@", _sourceData);

        [_sourceTable reloadData];

    }
} //Delete Data Cell
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [cell setBackgroundColor:_cellBackgroundColor];
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [_sourceData count];
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];

        NSDictionary *innerDict = [_sourceData valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", (int)indexPath.row]];

        NSString *setText = [innerDict valueForKey:@"sourceName"];

        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(_leftMargin, cell.frame.size.height/2 - 7.5, 150, 15)];
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        [label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:_cellTitleFontSize]];
        [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [label setTextColor:_cellTextColor];
        [label setText:setText];
        [label sizeToFit];
        [cell addSubview:label];
    }

    return cell;
} //View Of cell
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 50.0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, me being an idiot forgot that I'd added the labels in manually rather than using the conventional methods.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];

    for (UIView *i in cell.subviews) {
        if ([i isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
            [i removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
....
```

Removes the previous labels from that cell prior to adding the new data.